# Does the expression "dark jewel of something" mean a good or a bad feature in something?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, metaphors

Does the expression "dark jewel of something" means a good or a bad feature in something?

Example:

> The dark jewel of Hume's epistemology is his sceptical argument
>   against induction and, while I cannot accept that argument, my largely
>   fruitless efforts to refute it have provided a primary focus for my
>   own philosophical work.

– "[The Epistemology of Testimony](http://www.metanexus.net/essay/epistemology-testimony)", by Peter Lipton

Comment: Note that "dark" has many metaphorical senses.  Aside from being literally of a dark color, it may imply something sinister, it may imply a sort of "downer" outlook on life, it may imply misfortune, or it may imply something else.  Without researching it, I would guess that the "downer" outlook is intended in this case.

Comment: It should be obvious from the quoted passage how the author feels about the "dark jewel".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a common English expression, it's probably a nonce coinage by the author.  With that said, it implies both.

It's a nicely poetic phrase employed to both praise and simultaneously disparage Hume's work.  I would hazard that he admires Hume's brilliance and skill (the "jewel"), but abhors the ends to which Hume has applied those traits (the "darkness").  To further expand upon the metaphor, the term "jewel" implies that this argument in particular is perhaps the most important and significant part of Hume's *oeuvre*, whereas "dark" adds mystical overtones of evil wizardry and sorcery (not to be taken literally, of course!) resulting in the author's inability to refute an argument he is convinced is wrong.